# Budibase chart not populating data from JSON based data provider

Tags: budibase

I'm currently trying to populate an analytics chat from a data source in budibase.

The datasource produces output that looks like so:

`{"enabled":8,"disabled":1,"total":9}`

The code for the data provider is here but in simple terms it counts the amount of JSON 'enabled' keys set to true or false from a previous rest API call:

```
let enabledCount = 0;
let disabledCount = 0;

const data = $("Users Scans.Rows");

data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.enabled) {
        enabledCount++;
    } else {
        disabledCount++;
    }
});

const totalCount = data.length;
const result = {
    enabled: enabledCount,
    disabled: disabledCount,
    total: totalCount
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
const jsondata = JSON.stringify(result);
return jsondata;
```

I've added a chart wtihin that data provider and can click it as a data source but none of the other data populates for the chart options includign drawing chart on the page see chart config below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYTHA.png)

I've tried many different ways including removign the data provider and simply adding the data parsing into the chart, outputting the data as CSV and different chart types. I have had it work previously but cannot figure otu what changed. The REST API call is working as intended and retrives data no problem.